# Access the faces and vertex of 2d Apollonius diagram CGAL- Weighted Voronoi diagram

Tags: c++, cgal, voronoi

When I try using the following code to access the faces and vertices of Apollonius Voronoi Diagram (Reference : [CGAL 2D APOLLONIUS diagram for Weighted Voronoi - How to generate and get the faces and vertices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274584/cgal-2d-apollonius-diagram-for-weighted-voronoi-how-to-generate-and-get-the-fa))

```
for(A_Bounded_faces_iterator f = VDA.bounded_faces_begin(); f != VDA.bounded_faces_end(); f++)
    {

        A_Ccb_halfedge_circulator ec_start = (f)->ccb();
        A_Ccb_halfedge_circulator ec = ec_start;
        poly.clear();
        do {
            x = ((A_Halfedge_handle)ec)->source()->point().x();
            y = ((A_Halfedge_handle)ec)->source()->point().y();
            poly.push_back(QPointF(x,y));
        } while ( ++ec != ec_start );        
        List_Poly.push_back(poly);
    }
```

I get the following error

```
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Assertion_exception'
  what():  CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: incircle(f, p) == NEGATIVE
File: /usr/include/CGAL/Apollonius_graph_2.h
Line: 1050**
```

I dont know why the assertion is getting violated. Please can you help me as I need to access the faces and vertices of apollonius diagram for my problem. Is there any other way i can access the faces and vertices of apollonius diagram.